# Monitoring Azure AD B2C number of authentications

Tags: azure, entra-id

I may be still in the free tier of my Azure AD B2C - https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/pricing/details/active-directory-b2c/ but I need to understand the speed of consumption and current number of used authentications in my tenant. I have tried looking not only to google and other sources, but also the Metrics, Cost Management and Billing and other areas of my Azure subscription but can't find the exact or in fact any number of authentications except going through the individual lines of logs in the B2C service directly.

Is there some collected view of this? I do also find it funny that the B2C has to live in their own directory instead of the "original" one where the subscription is but I guess that's just how it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been able to get an answer from Microsoft support team:

> I’ve reviewed the response from our internal teams, but in summary they’ve reaffirmed that at the moment no live billing information is available for AAD B2C. Since the service is still in public preview, monitoring the actual usage on a day to day basis for the current billing period is as of yet unsupported, and there is no ETA on when such feature would become available.